# Python wrapper function calling another function with arguments passing through is erroring out

Tags: python, function, loops, date, wrapper

I have a long function pulling data out of an API (not included here).  I use the following call to get the function:

```
get_hourly_WSI_latlong_historical (startdate, enddate, lat, long, fields = None)
```

Below is the range of dates I want to pull in data for:

```
startdate = datetime.date(2011, 9, 6)
enddate = datetime.date(2014, 10, 12)
```

Per the recommendation of a stack overflow member, I am using the following wrapper_function to get the resulting data frame created from the above date range.

```
def my_wrapper_func(startdate, enddate):
    middle_years = range(startdate.year+1, enddate.year)
    _all = []
    _all.append(get_hourly_WSI_latlong_historical(startdate, datetime(startdate.year, 12, 31)), 42.281, 83.743)
    for year in middle_years:
        _all.append(get_hourly_WSI_latlong_historical(datetime(year, 1, 1), datetime(year, 12, 31)), 42.281, 83.743)
    _all.append(get_hourly_WSI_latlong_historical(datetime(enddate.year, 1, 1), datetime(enddate.year, 12, 31)), 42.281, 83.743)
    return _all

my_wrapper_func(datetime(2010, 2, 1), datetime(2015, 2,1))
```

Unforunately I am getting the following error:

[image: error message]

**What can I do to resolve this issue and get the code to run successfully?**  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have redundant closing brackets after `datetime(startdate.year, 12, 31)` in lines:

```
_all.append(get_hourly_WSI_latlong_historical(startdate, datetime(startdate.year, 12, 31)), 42.281, 83.743)
_all.append(get_hourly_WSI_latlong_historical(datetime(enddate.year, 1, 1), datetime(enddate.year, 12, 31)), 42.281, 83.743)
```

Those closing brackets should be in the end of lines:

```
_all.append(get_hourly_WSI_latlong_historical(startdate, datetime(startdate.year, 12, 31), 42.281, 83.743))
_all.append(get_hourly_WSI_latlong_historical(datetime(enddate.year, 1, 1), datetime(enddate.year, 12, 31), 42.281, 83.743))
```

Also it would be good to add `import datetime`, for example like so:

```
import datetime as dt
```

and use it in statements:

```
startdate = dt.date(2011, 9, 6)
enddate = dt.date(2014, 10, 12)

_all.append(get_hourly_WSI_latlong_historical(startdate, dt.datetime(startdate.year, 12, 31), 42.281, 83.743))
_all.append(get_hourly_WSI_latlong_historical(dt.datetime(enddate.year, 1, 1), dt.datetime(enddate.year, 12, 31), 42.281, 83.743))
```

Comment: thank you...I made your suggested fix in my code but got the following error: "module object is not callable" and it is pointing to the last line of code:    my_wrapper_func(datetime(2010, 2, 1), datetime(2015, 2,1))  ....thoughts?

Comment: Updated `datetime` issue